# R if else statement within rows

Tags: r

I have the data

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
   [1,]    0    0    0
   [2,]    0    1    0
   [3,]    0    1    0
   [4,]    0    0    0
   [5,]    1    0    0
   [6,]    1    0    0
```

For each row, if the first value is 1, then let the third value be 1; if the second value is 1, then let the third value be 2. So my resulted data should looks like

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
   [1,]    0    0    0
   [2,]    0    1    2
   [3,]    0    1    2
   [4,]    0    0    0
   [5,]    1    0    1
   [6,]    1    0    1
```

My attempt using an if else statement within for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data[i,1] == 1){
    data[i,3] == 1
  } else if(data[i,2] == 1){
    data[i,3] == 2
  }else{
    data[i,3] == 0
  }
}
```

The resulted third column is still a column of zeros. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Use `<-`, not `==`.  (If you insist, you can use `=` instead, but `==` means something else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `replace`

```
m[, 3] <- replace(m[, 1], m[, 2] == 1, 2)
m
#     V1 V2 V3
#[1,]  0  0  0
#[2,]  0  1  2
#[3,]  0  1  2
#[4,]  0  0  0
#[5,]  1  0  1
#[6,]  1  0  1
```

**data**

```
m <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("V1", "V2", "V3")))
```